# Is it true that Suzanne Collins was forced to add a love triangle to the Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games, love, publishing, suzanne-collins

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/YMMV/TheHungerGames) states that Collins' publishers forced her to change Gale from Katniss's cousin to a love interest. I've heard this before in different places but sometimes the facts are slightly different. Usually the popularity of the *Twilight* series is mentioned as the cause. I have, however, been unable to find any proof of this.

Can anybody find something to prove or disprove the rumor?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The most authoritative reference I can find is in [this interview](http://blog.sarahlaurence.com/2010/11/interview-with-kate-egan-editor-of.html) with Collins's editor Kate Egan:

> *What are Suzanne Collins’s strengths and weaknesses as a writer, and how do you help her as an editor?*
>
> Storytelling is Suzanne’s strength. As an editor, I help her develop the characters. For example, **I asked her for more of the Peeta-Katniss-Gale love triangle**. Suzanne was more focused on the war story. We’ve learned to trust each other. Sometimes Suzanne thinks it’s obvious where she is going, but I tell her I don’t see it. When I need help following, it’s a sign that the manuscript needs some shoring up.

Which suggests the love triangle *was* there originally, but the author wanted to put less focus on it.

Collins herself is [notoriously reclusive](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2012/apr/27/suzanne-collins-hunger-games-profile), and has given very few interviews relating to the Hunger Games, none of which seem to mention this issue, so it looks like this is the best we're going to get.

Comment: Also, her editor seems like a jerk.

Comment: IMO, her editor seems like an editor.